# API Design: Expressing search criteria in XML

Tags: xml, web-services, architecture

Last year, my group developed a web service that included basic search functionality. 
All search conditions where combined with a boolean AND:

```
<conditions>
  <condition name="name1">value1</condition>
  <condition name="name2">value2</condition>
<conditions>
```

... is equivalent to name1=value1 AND name2=value2 etc.

Now, we have been asked to expand the search feature to allow for more complex searches. 
I see two plausible approaches:

**OPTION #1: Let users pass in their own SQL query (either full clause, or just the 'where).**

Examples:

```
<where>Cost = 5000.00 OR Cost > 5000.00</where>
<query>SELECT cmis:name FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:name LIKE '%test%'</query>
```

Precedent:

- [SearchSQL.SetWhereClause](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.net.doc/M_FileNet_Api_Query_SearchSQL_SetWhereClause_1_bb3a7a4f.htm) in IBM's FileNet API
- [Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905420)
- ADO uses this approach in various places. For example, [recordset.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

Advantages:

- Our schema stays simple. We could leave the "<conditions>" approach in place for the simple use cases, and add an alternative syntax.
- We'd just use the WHERE clause directly server-side (after scrubbing for sql injection) == cleaner code server side
- Follows industry standards (does it? CMIS, Microsoft ... anything from the Java world?)

Disadvantages:

- Not exactly "elegant xml" (is there any such thing?). Potentially forces consumers of the service to do some hackish string manipulation on their side, rather than providing them with something more elegant.

**OPTION #2. Revamp our <conditions> approach to allow more granular queries in the soap request.**

Example (from FetchXML):

```
 <filter type='and'> 
     <condition attribute='lastname' operator='ne' value='Cannon' /> 
 </filter>
```

Precedent:

- [FetchXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328117.aspx)
- [Ant gets close](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) with <if> / <else>

Advantages:

- Arguably more consistent with what an end user would expect (often the mark of a good API)
- Potential to give end users cleaner code
- Doesn't create dependency on SQL language / backend. Keeps it abstract

Disadvantages:

- More server-side code required to reconstruct the XML into the SQL statement the user meant in the first place

I hope that the examples, precedent, advantages, and disadvantages give enough background to avoid subjective answers. I am looking for answers grounded in standards and best practices.

My question is: are there definitive reasons for choosing one approach over the other in expanding an API?

Comment: Why represent them in XML in the first place?

Comment: It's a web service. The XML is specified by the XSDs in the WSDL.

Comment: You need logical operators AND relational operators as part of your search criteria?

Comment: Yes - AND, OR, NOT, >, >=, <, <= etc. The full range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #2, if only for one reason: security.

Allowing end users to pass arbitrary SQL to your database is an invitation to disaster.  You either trust your users to NEVER make mistakes in SQL, or you have to write code to determine which SQL you're going to accept and which SQL you're going to reject.

Option #2 will be harder to design and implement, but option #1 guarantees that you will hate yourself at some point when some user updates every record in an important table.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with DWRoelands on Option #1 is probably a bad idea from security perspective.

I would suggest an Option #3 that is similar to your Option #2 but use a DSL(Domain Specific Language). So you will have something like:

```
<condition expression="$firstname='John' and $lastname !='Doe'"/>
```

The server will then need to have a parser to compile and run the expression. You are free to design the syntax of the expression to suit your needs.

I have personally implemented your option #2 and the DSL before. I like DSL better because of it's flexibility and it makes my XML looks cleaner. You're right that this approach will require more server-side coding, but I prefer to do more work than letting user do more work.

Comment: Thank you for this answer -- I actually like this better myself and I can see where it makes for more elegant syntax. Our team voted for Option #1 but I'll keep this in mind for the future.